# Issues with either how I'm downloading mobileconfig files (JavaScript below) or how iOS is dealing with it (not sure)

Tags: javascript

So I created something that allows people to create and download the created .mobileconfig file without the need of a mac (because AC2 is only on macOS) and it's a lot faster to just do it on device. Issue is that when people are downloading it, it prompts as "Do you want to download (filename.mobileconfig) rather than the usual "This website is trying to download a config profile. Do you want to allow this?". This introduces an additional few steps rather than the "click allow, check in settings, and install" option, which is what I'm going for.

I know that it will prompt the correct way if the URL points to the mobileconfig file, except that requires the .mobileconfig file to be stored on the server hosting my site, which I want to avoid if possible, and stick to just HTMl and JavaScript if possible.

This is the JavaScript that's "downloading" the file:

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}

document.getElementById("DownloadProfileBTN").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var text = document.getElementById("generated_profile_content").textContent;
    var filename = "config.mobileconfig";
    download(filename, text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot control this.

I have tested this extensively in the four major browsers on iOS, MacOS, and Windows (no Android, and no Windows phones). As of Q1 2022, most major **mobile** browsers still have embarrassingly bad UX for saving files to disk after they have been transferred to the browser *using javascript*. One notable exception is Safari on iOS, which has a unique (and pleasant) UI download prompt.

Most other **mobile** browsers have only one path: attempt to render the transferred file in the browser viewport, and rely on the user to long-press on the visible render and choose "Save As...". This is true whether the file is something most browsers can natively render (i.e. images), or is some complex format like an Office document. Edge has a cool footer with a Download button, but when I was doing my research, it literally never worked. (Microsoft has spent >20 years mastering the art of building terrible web browsers.)

**Desktop** browsers behave much better across the board: the `<a download="filename" ...>` approach in your sample gives a seamless instant-download experience in the major browsers. You can programmatically create that link, click it, then remove it from the DOM after a brief delay, and the file will immediately materialize in the user's normal downloads folder.

IIRC, this situation is different if you *don't* use javascript to manage the download. That is: just have an anchor whose `href` points to a URL that will respond with a [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header. This is vastly simpler for the front-end, but there are other reasons people don't use this approach. If that's your situation, you may be stuck.

None of this is unique to `.mobileconfig` files. It's been a long time since I read up on those, but I seem to recall that mobile platforms that consume that type have special handling -- but again, *only when it's a direct download* rather than being transferred via JS.

Note that this doesn't actually have anything to do with the transfer itself. These troubles flow from the fact that after your JS has transferred the data, it still has to do *something* to instruct the browser to save the data as a file on disk. The transfer itself is unremarkable and creates no problems, but is pointless if you don't then save it. You don't have many options for writing the file to disk. That feature space is still pretty crappy, I suspect because there are so many extremely important security implications of giving random webpages the power to create local files.

Another fun challenge is that feature-detection will not work here. The basic tools for saving a file technically do exist in all the major browsers (FileReader, ObjectURLs, etc), they all just work differently (and badly). (I think this is Goodhart's Law at work.) Edge has a proprietary `msSaveBlob`, but like I said, their footer button thing still seems pretty shoddy.

---

One alternative I have not had an opportunity to test is to use a WebWorker to save the file. IIRC, WebWorkers have the ability to write files to disk, and I was hopeful that it might work the same way in all the browsers. But my project timeline did not have room to spend a day or two experimenting.